# How can one view the entire string of a JSON file in HugeJsonViewer?

Tags: windows, string, json

I use [HugeJsonViewer](https://github.com/WelliSolutions/HugeJsonViewer) to browse the JSON file. How can one view the entire string of a JSON file in HugeJsonViewer? I can only see the beginning:

[image]

Comment: Try another tool, such as free JSONEdit,, https://tomeko.net/software/JSONedit/?lang=en, which shows as text, tree or list and can scroll the full line width.

Comment: Author of the tool: I recall a massive performance drop when I showed all strings in full length, which is why I put an ellipsis there. Sorry. At the moment I'd say it's not supported.

Comment: @ThomasWeller interesting, thanks! you're welcome to add it as an answer.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik thanks, unfortunately JSON files larger than 20 MB becomes very slow with JSONEdit

Comment: Ah! that combines with @ThomasWeller comment -- choice of speed or completeness. Workaround: JSON is readable text, so you could still use *HugeJsonViewer*, with the file open concurrently in Notepad, Notepad++, or a hex editor, and search on a string such as "the track is untimed" to view the full text. *sigh*